# short tenor url link won't work in discord.js embed (and I don't know how to turn it into a gif link)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

so I was trying to make a gif command in javascript for my discord bot. it sends the embed but it seems the gif is taking forever to load. when I click on the link it opens the page just fine.

```
const { EmbedBuilder, MessageType } = require("discord.js");
const Tenor = require("tenorjs").client({
  Key: process.env.TENORAPI,
  Filter: "off",
  Locale: "en_US",
});
require("dotenv/config");
exports.run = async (client, message, prefix) => {
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length + 3).trim();
  const person = message.author;
  Tenor.Search.Random(args, "1")
    .then((Results) => {
      Results.forEach((Post) => {
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
          .setAuthor({
            name: `here is your ${args} gif, ${person.username} ;)`,
            iconURL: person.displayAvatarURL(),
            url: Post.url,
          })
          .setImage(Post.url);
        message.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
      });
    })
    .catch(console.error);
  console.log(args);
};
exports.name = "gif";
```

[here is a photo of the message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCogJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest grabbing Tenor's api data directly, the original url can be found in the json data, and this url can be displayed in the embed.